# Wrapped Drawable displays unproperly

Tags: android, xml

I'm making an Android Studio app, In this app I have an original drawable (accentb), this drawable is just a rounded button of the accent color.
This is the accentb.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        />
</shape>
```

In a part of my application, I take this drawable and change its color by making a copy and wrapping it (I just need to change the color for another one, but I need to keep the same shape), but, when it displays, it does it unproperly, it does not fills the entire LinearLayout (I apply this WrappedDrawable to a LinearLayout, simulating a Button).

```
        Drawable unwrappedDrawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.accentb);
        Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, color);
        linearButton.setBackgroundDrawable(wrappedDrawable);
```

[This is how the wrapped drawable looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KffDl.png)

How Could I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wrapped drawable was being applied to a LinearLayout, it shown a rounded rectangle. So I replaced the LinearLayout with a drawable to just a CardView that changes its color.